# Does google dart support es6 proxies?

Tags: ecmascript-6, dart

Does dart support es6 Proxy? I couldnt find the information in the official documentation. Even searching in google didnt give me any results.

The reason im asking:

Im trying to detect when a certain property changes. Similar to C# INotifyPropertyChanged.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What would Dart need that for? Dart is not another way of writing JS, Dart is it's own language that compiles to JS, what the JS looks like exactly shouldn't really matter.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I assume something like this will do? https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/observable

Comment: I don't understand how they would be related. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer im trying to detect if a property changes and call a function based on it. Similar to C# INotifyPropertyChanged etc

Comment: Yes, you can use observables for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: not directly.

As Gunter mentioned, the [observable package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/observable) can be used to accomplish things that look like INotifyPropertyChanged from .NET.